# Append model builder overrides in partial for default SQL values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

We are using EF Core database first in a project. I noticed that EF Core is not picking up the default values for DateTimes in the generated models / context. As a result, EF throws an error if you don't set the value of that DateTime in the model before adding it to the DbContext. It is defaulted to DateTime.Min and I really don't want to make this column nullable. Schema example would be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Blog](
    [BlogId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Blog_Created] DEFAULT (GETDATE())
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Blog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BlogId] ASC) 
            WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

I [found that you can add the following in the OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values), in order to tell EF that this column is defaulted by SQL, and to ignore it.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to manually change the generated DbContext file, because whenever someone updates the database and re-scaffolds the manual changes will be lost.

Since the generated DbContext is a partial, I can add my own code into the separate partial. However, I can't do this, since the OnModelCreated is overriden in the generated code.

```
public partial class MyContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options): base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // of course this won't build...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

How can I add configuration to the model builder in my custom partial extensions file?

Comment: Isn't `.HasDefaultValueSql` the same as using the `DefaultValueAttribute`? Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: One way I can think of is to create and use a derived context (in order to be able to override `OnModelCreating`).

Comment: Why do you need to write the configuration? I took your table and scaffold it from database it correctly generated DefaultValueSql call in OnModelCreating method.

Comment: This is bad practice for database security.  Using the EF is fine, but use stored procedures with parameters instead.  Do not dynamically build SQL using EF.  This is recommended in several programming security books because of the risk of SQL injection.